# OPTIONS for pgsql_fdw

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am exploring the [pgsql_fdw](http://interdbconnect.sourceforge.net/pgsql_fdw/pgsql_fdw-en.html) module and I have run into the following situation:

I have a local db that is a copy of a remote db, but the data is different. Development vs production.  I wanted to create a foreign table that pointed to the production version. Since the docs indicated that the name of the foreign table had to be unique I decided to create a fdw schema and place all the foreign tables within it. I performed:

```
create foreign table foreign_table(columna bigint, columnb text)  
server foreign_server;
```

Apparently however pgsql_fdw uses a 1 to 1 mapping between fully_qualified table names, and of course "fdw.foregin_table" does not exist on the foreign_server, it's "public.foreign_table", and so I get:

```
ERROR:  could not execute EXPLAIN for cost estimation  
DETAIL:  ERROR:  schema "fdw" does not exist
```

In the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) there is an options parameter to CREATE FOREIGN TABLE:

```
OPTIONS ( option 'value' [, ...] )  
Options to be associated with the new foreign table.  
The allowed option names and values are specific to each foreign data wrapper  
and are validated using the foreign-data wrapper's validator function.  
Option names must be unique.
```

My question(s) are: What are the OPTIONS for pgsql_fdw? Is there a specific option to specify the foreign table name rather than assume the remote and local are the same?

Comment: Figured out how to use the dblink contrib module instead. Install the dblink contrib module set up a dblink connection: select dblink_connect('connection_name', 'host=hostname dbname=fdbname user=user password=secret');create foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw validator postgresql_fdw_validator;create server dblink_fdw_server foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw options(hostaddr 'hostname', dbname 'fdbname');select * from dblink('connection_name', 'select * from public.foreigntable') as foreign_table(columna bigint, columnb text);
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html

Comment: Can you add this as a solution?  I would be happy to upvote.

Comment: I will have to make sure its not outdated.  I am sure the fdw code has progressed since this question.

Comment: My review of 9.2 is that there were not a lot of changes.  At any rate as long as this is tagged as 9.1 the basic features and behavior won't change in a stable release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested promoting my comment solution to answer:

Figured out how to use the dblink contrib module instead.
Install the dblink contrib module set up a dblink connection:

```
select dblink_connect('connection_name', 'host=hostname dbname=fdbname user=user password=secret');
create foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw validator postgresql_fdw_validator;
create server dblink_fdw_server foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw options(hostaddr 'hostname', dbname 'fdbname');
select * from dblink('connection_name', 'select * from public.foreigntable') as foreign_table(columna bigint, columnb text);
```

Reference: [postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html](http://postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html)

Answer (score 2):

The options you need are :

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE your_local_shema.your_local_table (
  field_1 int, field_2 int, ...
)
SERVER foreign_server
OPTIONS (SCHEMA_NAME 'your_remote_schema', TABLE_NAME 'your_remote_table')
```